# dark mode not working for received html emails thunderbird 91.7 / Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird

I can enable dark mode in thunderbird (`tools/preferences/Add-ons and Themes`).
However received emails still have white background and black text color.

It seems that this comes from the fact that the emails are written in html (mostly company emails) and not plain text.

If I go to `View / Message Body As / Plain Text` the text now shows in the dark colors I specified under `tools / preferences / general / Language & Appearance / colors` where I configured some dark-mode-like colors.

However now all my emails have bad formatting.

Can I achieve the same result without switching to plain text view?

My specs:
Thunderbird 91.7 64bit
Windows 10

Comment: Those HTML emails most likely explicitly _specify_ the colors - in which case an "automatic darkmode" simply does not work.

Comment: You can ask the creators of these emails to also add a dark mode to emails via CSS. Don't know for sure about thunderbird, but some mailclients support dark-mode CSS for mails.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose `View / Message Body As / Simple HTML`, messages will be displayed with the colors you configured while still retaining some HTML formatting.